# Type from a custom C++ library within Cython?

Tags: cython

I'm working on wrapping some code via Cython. The C++ implementation can be found [palisade-python-demo ckks_wrapper.h](https://gitlab.com/palisade/palisade-python-demo/-/blob/master/src/ckks_wrapper.h). For the moment, I'm focusing on wrapping the class `CiphertextInterfaceType`, copied below for convenience.

```cpp
#include <palisade.h>

namespace pycrypto {

/*
 * Ciphertext python wrapper
 */
class CiphertextInterfaceType {
 public:
  /**
   * Default constructor
   */
  CiphertextInterfaceType();

  /**
   * Constructor from Ciphertext
   */
  CiphertextInterfaceType(lbcrypto::Ciphertext<lbcrypto::DCRTPoly> ciphertext);

  /**
   * Destructor
   */
  ~CiphertextInterfaceType();

  const lbcrypto::CiphertextImpl<lbcrypto::DCRTPoly> &GetCiphertext() const;

 private:
  lbcrypto::Ciphertext<lbcrypto::DCRTPoly> m_ciphertext;
};
}
```

The issue I'm facing is I don't know how to "wrap" or work with `lbcrypto::CiphertextImpl<lbcrypto::DCRTPoly>`, which I'll call `cipherType` for short. `cipherType` is a custom type from an external library not in the standard. I need to 1) declare it as a private variable, 2) make a constructor that takes it, and 3) implement a getter.

---

Below is my `.pxd` file, (the cython "header" equicalent?)

```py
cdef extern from "ckks_wrapper.cpp":
    pass

cdef extern from "ckks_wrapper.h" namespace "pycrypto":
    cdef cppclass CiphertextInterfaceType:
        ####################################
        # Attrs
        ####################################
        # TODO: define the private variable m_ciphertext from above

        ####################################
        # Constructors/ destructors
        ####################################
        CiphertextInterfaceType() except +

        # TODO: the constructor below is supposed to accept an 
        CiphertextInterfaceType() except +

        ####################################
        # Methods
        ####################################
        # TODO:
            # Implement the *GetCiphertext
```

So, I've worked my way through the cython tutorial about wrapping some `Rectangle` class, [Cython - wrapping Rectangle](https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/wrapping_CPlusPlus.html) which helped, but I'm clearly missing a few things. How do I "define" the type `cipherType` within my `.pxd` file?

---

#### Followup to DavidW

1. Understanding the "linking"

So, my `ckks_wrapper.hpp` has a namespace, `pycrypto`. In the `ckks_wrapper.hpp`, I also `include <palisade.h>` which itself has namespace `lbcrypto`. Based on the answer, does it mean that I can directly access the namespace of the library `palisade.h`, `lbcrypto`, and the Cython compiler will know to look in `palisade.h`?

I just want to make sure I understand

2. Understanding the code.

Regarding where to define the `CiphertextDCRTPoly "Ciphertext<DCRTPoly>"`

```py
cdef extern from "ckks_wrapper.cpp":
    pass

cdef extern from "ckks_wrapper.hpp" namespace "libcrypto":
    cdef cppclass CiphertextDCRTPoly "Ciphertext<DCRTPoly>":
        pass


cdef extern from "ckks_wrapper.h" namespace "pycrypto":
    cdef cppclass CiphertextInterfaceType:
        ...
```

or

```py
cdef extern from "ckks_wrapper.cpp":
    pass

cdef extern from "ckks_wrapper.h" namespace "pycrypto":
    cdef extern from "ckks_wrapper.hpp" namespace "libcrypto":
        cdef cppclass CiphertextDCRTPoly "Ciphertext<DCRTPoly>":
            pass
    cdef cppclass CiphertextInterfaceType:
        ...
        CiphertextInterfaceType(CiphertextDCRTPoly) except +
        ...
```

I'm leaning towards the second, because if not I don't see how I'd be able to use "CiphertextDCRTPoly" in `CiphertextInterfaceType`

Comment: You definitely can't (and don't need to) declare the private variable. You only need to declare the bits of the public interface you plan to use.

Comment: Thank you! That's strange to me... I just assumed I'd be able to do it with a `__X` like in a python class....  Do you have any idea of how I should proceed with the `lbcrypto::Ciphertext<lbcrypto::DCRTPoly>` type? It's really stumping me.

Comment: The first option - they shouldn't be nested. `cdef extern...` line does a few things: first it generates `#include something.h` in the generated Cython c++ file (allowing the C++ compiler to use the contents). It doesn't matter if the classes are ultimate in another file with a chain of includes. Second it tells Cython that everything in the block is an external declaration within the namespace given. This means that Cython knows how to use some functions of the class and knows to generate C++ code like `pycrypto::CiphertextInterfaceType`

Comment: Gotcha! So by doing `cdef extern from "ckks_wrapper.h" namespace "lbcrypto":`, we are essentially telling Cython to look for `lbcrypto` from within `ckks_wrapper.h`. Since `lbcrypto` is inside `palisade.h` , Cython will just look in `palisade.h`

Comment: Assuming I'm correct, I think I understand all of this now! Thank you so so much for your help. If I'm misunderstanding this please do correct me

Comment: Yes, I think you understand that correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, you don't need to declare it as a private variable. There's no way to do this or purpose in doing this. Responding to your suggestion in the comments that you might be able to use double underscores (`__x`) analagous to Python: there's no way for Cython to generate C++ code that can access the private variable therefore there's no value in this.

As a general rule, Cython only needs to know about the parts of the public interface that you want to access. So if you don't need the other functions you can happily omit them too. I'll assume you do though.

Cython does have [some understanding of C++ templates](https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/wrapping_CPlusPlus.html#templates) using square brackets. There are limitations here but you can cover most code:

```
cdef extern from "somewhere.hpp" namespace "libcrypto":
   cdef cppclass Ciphertext[T]
       pass

   cdef cppclass DCRTPoly:
       pass
```

You'd then declare the constructor and function as you'd expect, using `CiphertextInterfaceType[DCRTPoly]` as the argument.

Alternatively, you could skip using templates and just use Cython's ["cname" feature](https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/external_C_code.html#resolving-naming-conflicts-c-name-specifications) where you name the Cython wrapper one thing, but provide it with an alternative name to use when it generates code:

```
cdef extern from "something.hpp" namespace "libcrypto":
    cdef cppclass CiphertextDCRTPoly "Ciphertext<DCRTPoly>":
        pass
```

This may make sense if `Ciphertext<DCRTPoly>` is the only version of the template you're planning to use.

Comment: Thank you so so much! I upvoted yout answer. I'll get around to testing it and I'll mark it as correct. As a side note, do you have any recommendations for resources for Cython? I could not for the life of me find what you mentioned anywhere. Or am I just looking in the wrong places in the documentation?

Comment: There's a big c++ page in the documentation that's often helpful. The "cname" trick is hard to search for (but it is useful). The principle that "you don't have to tell Cython about stuff that you don't plan to use" probably isn't documented anywhere (and maybe it should be)

Comment: I've edited my question to add followups to make sure I understand what's happening. Thank you so so much for your help! I'm looking through the documentation now but from my skim there's nothing that answers my questions